# Checking if IP is already whitelisted for a URL?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am using this scriptblock to white list IP:

```
invoke-command -computername $($server.text) -credential c\r {
    param($ip, $mask, $boolean, $url)

    Set-Location "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv";
    .\appcmd.exe set config "$($url)" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='$($ip)',allowed='$($boolean)',subnetMask='$($mask)']" /commit:apphost    
} -ArgumentList $ip.Text, $mask.Text, $allowed, $url.Text
```

Is there a way to check (using `appcmd`) if given IP is already whitelisted or not?

If I use this command:

```
.\appcmd.exe list config "$($url)" -section:system.webserver/security/ipsecurity
```

I am able to view the `<system.webserver><security><ipsecurity>` section of config file. How can I fetch IPs in an array from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way to achieve this would be :

putting values into a xml object :

```
$ipsettings = [xml](.\appcmd.exe list config "$($url)" -section:system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)
```

Then accessing desired node (in this case  ipaddress):

```
$ipsettings.SelectNodes("//add") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ipaddress"
```

Answer above is pretty much like this (infact thank him for guiding me), but that dint work for me.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/

Read this brilliant post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ipsettings = [xml](.\appcmd.exe list config "$($url)" -section:system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)
```

will yield a PowerShell XmlNode object. You can search that through various methods. To get a plain list of the IP addresses use

```
$ipsettings.SelectNodes("//ipSecurity/add/@ipAddress") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
```

To check for a single address use

```
$ip = "192.12.231.22"
$resultNode = $ipSettings.SelectSingleNode("//ipSecurity/add[@ipAddress='$ip' and @allowed='true']")
$resultNode -ne $null
```

Comment: I have two whitelisted IP's in a particular URL, but when i try to fetch it into a xml object and then print them using what you suggested, i get a blank list.